# How do I pass multiple non-empty values of a struct to hmset in golang?

Tags: go, redis

With reference to this:
https://play.golang.org/p/0kYRHO5f7kE

If I have 20+ different fields, if one of the fields in the Struct is empty, don't update it. Only update the ones with values in them.

What's the best way forward? I've seen passing as variadic input to another function but how best can I do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this](https://github.com/fatih/structs) library to convert your struct fields into map of interfaces (can be done by yourself using reflect from stdlib) then loop over it

```
pipe := redisClient.TxPipeline()

m := structs.Map(server)
for k, v := range m {
    pipe.HMSet(username, k, v)
}

cmder, err := pipe.Exec()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

the driver for redis used is [go-redis](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis)

Comment: this is not very elegant as it does a loop call (meaning multiple round trip to redis)  instead of one trip. what's a better solution?

Comment: transaction and lua script are other ways

Comment: can you point me to transaction? what do you mean by transaction?

Comment: edited the answer. but at all, you need to redesign what you're doing, seems so wrong